# Multi level nested list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to implement multi levels on the nested List of Material-UI and my problem is that if i have more than one nested list and clicked on one of them, it opens all of them, not the clicked one only and i can understand why but i don't know how to fix that.

```
render() {
    const { doc } = this.props;
    return (
      <List
        component="nav"
        aria-labelledby="nested-list-subheader"
        subheader={
          <ListSubheader component="div" id="nested-list-subheader">
            {doc.title}
          </ListSubheader>
        }
        className="font-weight-bolder"
      >
        {doc.subTopics.map(x => (
          <div>
            <ListItem button key={x.id} onClick={this.handleClick}
            >
              <ListItemText primary={x.title} />
              {this.state.open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
            </ListItem>
            <Collapse
              key={x.id}
              in={this.state.open}
              timeout='auto'
              unmountOnExit
            >
              {
                x.subSubTopics.map(toc => {
                  return (
                    this.state.urls.push(toc.url),

                    <List component='li' disablePadding key={x.id} primary={x.title}>
                      <div>
                        <ListItem button key={toc.header} primary={toc.header}>
                          <ListItemIcon>
                            {toc.technicalformat == "video" ? <i className="fa fa-play-circle"></i> : null}
                          </ListItemIcon>
                          <ListItemText key={toc.header} primary={toc.header} onClick={() => { this.changeTopicTitle(toc.header, x.title) }} />
                        </ListItem>
                        <Divider />

                      </div>
                    </List>
                  );
                })}
            </Collapse>


          </div>

        ))}

      </List>
```

[image: an example of what is happening:]

Comment: You seem to be trying to control independently multiple items (expand/collapse) with single state variable. Also, `handleClick` body is missing from your code sample. I think it makes sense to append that. To solve this, you may follow same approach I suggested (and you didn't accept ;) in your question about dynamically added/removed form blocks.

Comment: Thank you for replaying! Really? i stuck at the same point every time then. can you please explain it with a class component solution?